# Weight painting in specific poses?

Tags: animation, rigging, weight-painting, pose-mode

Im trying to make a pair of sci-fi handcuffs for a game im making, but im having a problem, When I try to weight paint them blender paints them like if they were in the rest pose, instead of in the current animation.

Im using unity as a game engine, and there I have the option to lock some bones in an animation, this is the workflow I wanna use, but I cannot properly weight paint the handcuffs, so they keep around the wrists of the character.

Edit: In order to make more visual what Im trying to do here are some examples:

I've downloaded this armbinder model, its huge but that's not the point, here it is the position it should be, both the 3d mesh, and the rig in the armbinder animation. However it is not weight painted (but it is children of the rig)

[image]

No weight paint here on the hands, which is where I want the weight paint to be (hands, elbows, shoulders)

[image]

And this is what happens when I add weight paint in the hand bones, it instantly moves away, like if I were painting on the hands and the rig were in the rest pose

[image]

Notice how the mesh moves to the oppposite direction of the hand
[image]

And If I move the hand to where the rest position should be, the mesh comes back to it's normal form.
[image]

What I need is the mesh to actually move with the hands but to be able to weight paint the mesh while in the animation position so it deforms properly.

Any help on how I could do this? Im using blender 2.79, but Im open to work on any version if there is a fix for this in other updates.

Comment: hello could you please show some screenshots?

Comment: This is probably a bug; since it's 2.79, it'd be useless to report it.   I would strongly recommend trying out a new version (3.0 was just released.)  This will probably involve some re-learning, but there are a tremendous number of improvements, including bug fixes, since 2.79.